# Ajax value in the textbox disappearing after a click of a button

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a jquery which retrieves the values from the database using ajax and webmethod and it goes as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        SearchText();
    });
function SearchText() {
   $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "InsertPage.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('name').value + 
                        "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and the web method is

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string username)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT UserName from student_details 
           where UserName LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%'", con))

    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", username);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            result.Add(dr["UserName"].ToString());
        }
```

the textbox in which the ajax is used is

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student Name">
     <ItemTemplate>                    
        <input type="text" id="name" class = "autosuggest" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If I debug the program , the value in this ajax textbox is coming as null and the output in the textbox is coming empty as a result I am not able to go further and store the value in the database.

Comment: are you able to hit the web method.

Comment: yes I am able to hit the webmethod

Comment: did you checked the success part of jquery using alert as `alert(data.d);`

Comment: yes and the value is also coming in the alert box

Comment: After I added runat="server", its not able to hit the web method itself . please help me

Answer (score 0):

It is simple that the `controls` which does not have `runat="server"` will not postback it's value to there server.

You need to add `runat="server"` in that texbox only then you can get the value at the server.

```
<input type="text" id="name" class = "autosuggest" runat="server" />
```

If it does not work you can use a hidden field and use autocompelete events. 

And set the hidden field value on postback.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the 'name' on your input so it should be

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
```

Also your using jQuery so just get the value as follows:

```
$('#username').val(); //instead of document.getElementById()
```

Comment: I tried this but its still coming that Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Sir, Please help me sir I am stuck in this part for past 3 days now

Comment: See edit and check if it works I have made a slight change to the jquery on how to get value I missed out the #